# JS Cross Browser Compatibility Issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

This piece of code works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentOne=$("#instructions");
    currentOne.addClass("visibleLabel");

    $('map area').mousemove(function(e) {
        $(currentOne).removeClass("visibleLabel");
        currentOne = '#' + $(this).data('label');
        $(currentOne).addClass("visibleLabel");
    });

});
</script>

<img src="http://greenparty.org.uk/assets/images/site_graphics/national/greenmap.png"
    usemap="greenuk" id="theGreenMap">

<map name="greenuk">
    <area shape="poly" id="region-southeast"
          data-label="southeast" coords="256,485,262,486,285,542,301,531,344,536,349,547,298,577,263,574,234,587,205,577,202,562,216,513,214,499,247,498"
          alt="southEast" href="south-east" />
    <!-- etc. -->
</map>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ve9hywdq/1/ If you try it in Firefox you are unable to click the parts of the map you want but in Chrome you can.

Comment: How about a fiddle to test it?

Comment: which part isn't working?

Comment: Moe, try using the `debuggers` in those respective browsers to see what is going on... maybe it is breaking in Chrome, but Chrome is more forgiving. Use `F12` for Chrome Debugger, FireFox Firebug (needs to be installed), and for IE's debugger, and check the console tabs for thrown errors. Please provide a fiddle as well so we can see the code in action. Also add more context around your questions as to `a) what your code's goal is`, `b) what's not working,` and `c) what you've tried`

Comment: @Growler Thanks alot for the tips. I have added the fiddle, also ive installed firefox firebug and im playing about to try and figure out the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with your script (you can remove it entirely and the problem persists) and everything to do with your HTML.

`usemap` properties must have a leading `#`. According the [W3C spec on `<map>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#image-maps):

> The `usemap` attribute, if specified, must be a valid **hash-name reference** to a `map` element.

A [hash-name reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-hash-name-reference) is

> a string consisting of a "#" (U+0023) character followed by a string which exactly matches the value of the name attribute of an element

Your `usemap` value doesn't have a leading `#`, which Chrome accepts (outside the requirements of the spec) and Firefox does not. Adding a leading `#` to your `usemap` attribute fixes your code.